# IDLE autocomplete in a new file do not work

Tags: python, python-idle

If I testing my codes on IDLE the autocomplete its works but if I open a new file don't.

See there pictures below:

1. I just press CTRL + SPACE.

[image]

2. So.. don't work in this case:

[image]

I'll think there are some configuration for solve this, any one knows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python idle doesn't work that way. You get autocomplete in idle shell because values are deduced in every run. When you use files your program is not evaluated until you run. Because you can assign any type to a variable at run time, there is no way for idle to confirm the type of variable.

Understand with an example

```
>> a = dict()
>> a = set()
>> a.  # <-- autocomplete knows type of a is set
```

but the same code in a file

```
a = dict()
a = set()
a. # <-- How does idle come to know what this variable is without running
```

but when you run this file once your global variables will show autocomplete feature, but not the local scope variables.

Comment: Thanks for all explanations. I think this is a good implementation in a future for Python.. because others text editor has this functionality

Comment: I tried to do some improvement earlier with this Idle, but not everyone agreed. This is a bit dumb but goes swiftly with size and portability so big changes in near future is highly unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried saving the script as a *.py file before trying to use IDLE's autocomplete?

More than that, have you considered using a text editor with Python plugins, like Sublime Text and Atom? Or even a python-compatible IDE, like PyCharm, Spyder or even JupyterNotebook.

Comment: Yes I've tried. I don't like use any text editor because my scripts its simple for this moment. Thanks

Comment: Sublime Text 3, for example, is so light-weight, even it's portable (*.zip standalone) version. With a simple build you can get any returns you want, from the simple to the complex ones.